# How to remove a tagged WPF object from Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

The code below gives me the following error:

> CS1061 UIElementCollection does not contain a definition for Where and
> no accessible extension method Where accepting a first argument of
> type UIElementCollection could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
var object = main.Children.Where(c => "platform1".Equals(c.Tag)).First();
main.Children.Remove(object);
```

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Children` property type `UIElementCollection` does not implement the generic interface `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can't use it as source of the `Enumerable` extension methods like `Where`.

You would have to add a type cast method like

```
var obj = main.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(...);
```

Since you also want to access the `Tag` property of the `FrameworkElement` subclass, use something like this instead:

```
var obj = main.Children
              .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
              .Where(c => "platform1".Equals(c.Tag))
              .First();
```

Or shorter:

```
var obj = main.Children
              .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
              .First(c => "platform1".Equals(c.Tag));
```